# Any $1$-form (only on $S^3$?) can be uniquely written as a sum of a closed $1$-form and a coclosed $1$-form?

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, spherical-geometry, spherical-harmonics, gauge-theory

What is meant by saying that any $1$-form (only on $S^3$?) can be uniquely written as a sum of a closed $1$-form and a "co-closed" $1$-form?

[...Since $H^1$ of $S^3$ is trivial it follows that the required closed $1$-form is also exact and then for any $1$-form say $A$ (a gauge field) on $S^3$ one says that it uniquely determines a gauge fixed 1-form $B$ such that $A = d\phi + B+\cdots$ ]

Comment: It follows from the Hodge decomposition theorem, saying that any $k$-form $\alpha$ can be uniquely written as $\alpha = dA + \delta B + C$, where $C$ is harmonic. In your case, there is no harmonic one form on $\mathbb S^3$ as $H^1$ of $\mathbb S^3$ is trivial.

Comment: And this works for which manifolds? And what exactly is unique here? Any reference?

Comment: It works for at least all compact Riemannian manifolds. You can check the book "Riemannian geometry and geometric analysis" by J. Jost. There is a section giving the proof of the theorem (section 3.4 in 2011 edition).

Comment: Well, the Hodge decomposition works for all compact Riemannian manifolds, but some of them have nontrivial harmonic forms so some $1$-forms won't be a sum of closed and coclosed forms only. (Like on tori.)

Comment: @GunnarMagnusson It's been a while, but I seem to recall that a harmonic form on a compact manifold is *both* closed and coclosed. If this is correct, then any form is the sum of a  closed and coclosed form;   harmonic forms are put separately to achieve the uniqueness of decomposition.

Comment: @Post No Bills: Ah, you're right of course. I was thinking of exact forms instead of closed ones. :)

Answer (score 2):

Let $M$ be a compact Riemannian manifold. The Hodge Theorem states that for every $k$

$$\Omega^k(M) = d\Omega^{k-1}(M) \oplus \delta\Omega^{k+1}(M) \oplus \mathcal{H}^k(M)\quad \text{and}\quad H^k_{\text{dR}}(M) \cong \mathcal{H}^k(M)$$

where $\delta$ is the adjoint of $d$ and $\mathcal{H}^k(M) = \ker \Delta|_{\Omega^k(M)}$ is the space of harmonic $k$-forms. Therefore, any $k$-form $\omega$ on $M$ can be written uniquely as $\omega = d\alpha + \delta\beta + \gamma$ where $\alpha \in \Omega^{k-1}(M)$, $\beta \in \Omega^{k+1}(M)$, and $\gamma \in \mathcal{H}^k(M)$. As $d^2 = 0$ and $\delta^2 = 0$, $d\alpha$ is closed and $\delta\beta$ is coclosed. As $\gamma$ is harmonic, it is closed and coclosed (this follows from the fact that $(\Delta\gamma, \gamma) = \|d\gamma\|^2 + \|\delta\gamma\|^2$). Using the fact that the sum of (co)closed forms is (co)closed, $\omega$ is a sum of a closed form and a coclosed form, but not necessarily in a unique way:

$$\omega = \underbrace{(d\alpha + \gamma)}_{\text{closed}} + \underbrace{\delta\beta}_{\text{coclosed}} = \underbrace{d\alpha}_{\text{closed}} + \underbrace{(\delta\beta + \gamma)}_{\text{coclosed}}.$$

So, if $\omega$ can be written uniquely as the sum of a closed form and a coclosed form, it is necessary that $\gamma = 0$. This condition is also sufficient by the Hodge Theorem. Therefore, every $k$-form on $M$ can be written uniquely as the sum of a closed form and a coclosed form if and only if $H^k_{\text{dR}}(M) \cong \mathcal{H}^k(M) = 0$.

*Note:* The above discussion follows through in the exact same way for vector bundle valued forms.

---

The statement you are referring to is the specific case $M = S^3$, $k = 1$ which applies because $H^1_{\text{dR}}(S^3) = 0$.